# Jquery dialog box not close after ajax success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
function sendMsg(){

        $.ajax({
             beforeSend: function(){
                 $("#loading").dialog('open').html("<p>Please Wait...</p>");
              },
            url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/WhoopieeMerchantAppConversationList", //(dynamically generated by product item), //(dynamically generated by product item)
           type: "get",
           data:"to_userid="+document.getElementById('to_userid').value+"&store_id="+document.getElementById('store_id').value+"&merchant_id="+document.getElementById('merchant_id').value+"&msg="+document.getElementById('msg').value,
           success: ajaxSuccessHandler
        });
    }
    function ajaxSuccessHandler(obj) {
        if(obj=="error")
        {
            $('#loading').html("<p style='font-size:18px;'>Msg Already Sent</p>");
        }
        else
        {
            $("#loading").dialog("close");
            alert("Message Sent Successfully");
            var redirect_link = document.getElementById('redirect').value;
            setTimeout(function(){window.location.href=redirect_link},0);
        }
    }
```

i want to close dialog box after the ajax call, but it still show at the back of alert box, please help

Comment: Why alert??? Just write into the dialog before closing it

Comment: Because i want to redirect after pressing ok in alert box, not in dialog box

Comment: So use a modal dialog box. Alert will block ANY script. Alternatively put the alert inside the setTimeout

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to reuse the dialog as a modal dialog, try this

```
$("#loading").dialog("close");
setTimeout(function(){
  alert("Message Sent Successfully");
  window.location.href=document.getElementById('redirect').value;
},100)
```

or in the dialog creation have

```
close: function(){
  alert("Message Sent Successfully");
  window.location.href=document.getElementById('redirect').value;
},
```